# Changing screensaver images on Bookeen Odyssey

Tags: cybook, odyssey, bookeen

I have tried to figure out how I can chance the screensaver image on by Bookeen Odyssey. The [online FAQ](http://www.bookeen.com/en/supportfaq/showOne/id/91) says:

> Select the picture you want to set as screensaver and when the contextual menu appears confirm that you want to display this picture as screensaver.

I am not sure where to put the image and in what menu to select screensaver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not tried, but I think you can put the image anywhere. I have put it in the internal memory in the Pictures directory. Particularly I did not want to risk finding out what happens when you put it on an SD card and remove the card.

To set it a file `abc.jpg` as screensaver. Select the file via the front Button and then Library (if you have folder view on, go all the way up the directory tree and then to `Cybook` → `Pictures` first).

As the picture you want is displayed, click the front button and then `Menu`. 
Once the TAB `Picture` appears (top line `Fit Screen`) you are in the Picture context menu, there you have to scroll down. The last line—normally out of view—is 'Set as Screensaver`, make sure it is selected (✓).

You can have only one image as screensaver. Selecting another image, deselects the previous one.

Comment: Mine image was in between the many library books, I only found it after switching to folder view. Now it work.