# Personal screensaver random from a set on Bookeen Cybook Odyssey

Tags: odyssey, bookeen, screensaver

In [this answer](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/a/473/60) it describes how to set a screensaver image (that shows when the book-reader is switched off/standby).

If you deselect the screensaver the Odyssey shows one of series of (5 or so) images at random. I have not found these pictures as files on the book reader internal memory.

I would like to have my own set of images from which my bookreader would choose, not just the one I can select as with the aforementioned answer.

How can I achieve this? Or alternatively, where do the 'default' images come from (as I think I can figure out how to replace them once I know where they come from)?

Comment: I don't know for sure, so I won't put this as an answer. The images may be hard-coded as resources directly in the software. It doesn't appear you can achieve the same behavior as the default images (cycling through multiple images). You are limited to just one custom image at a time.

Comment: @ShimmyHacked you might be right. The other thing I have considered is that they were frontpages for ebooks, but I have not found yet which ones that would be, and if it is, it certainly not from all the books.

Comment: The user manual just states that it displays `a random image or your personal image previously loaded`. It's definitely vague about where the random image comes from. http://www.mff.cuni.cz/fakulta/lib/pdf/Cybook_navod.pdf (section 2.4, under "Screensaver" mode).

Comment: FWIW I removed all of the 'internally stored' ebooks, and the screensaving persisted as normal. Also removed `system/usr/screensaver.bin` which seems a dump for quick restoring of the screensaver image. Of course there is a whole part of the Linux 'disk' device that you cannot access via normal means at all, where the default screensaver images could hide.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible. Right now, you can either select only one image from your own documents, or the random set of Bookeen images, which reside on the partition not accessible by the user.